# Find an item by its position in a grid tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter, is there a way for me to reference a widget within a grid by its row and column, in the same way that you would be able to reference an item within a list (or list of lists) by knowing its position in the list?

Answer (score 6):

You can call the `.grid_slaves(row, column)` method on the parent widget; this will return a list (possibly empty) of the widgets in that cell.

You could also iterate over all of the child widgets (`.grid_slaves()` with no parameters, or `.winfo_children()`) and call `.grid_info()` on each one.  This returns a dictionary with `'row'` and `'column'` keys, along with various other grid parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I realised that I could solve my own problem in a much simpler way, by literally making a list of lists, with each sub-list containing all of the widgets for a single row, and therefore I can refer to each item through it's row and column.